# Change value of a label

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I want change the value from a Label using events with Javascript. On my button I have a event `onclick`, when you click it go to the especific function but I can't get him to do what I want. For example enable or disable a element.

I tried with a normal button and with a asp button, but it didnt work. The property Visible from Label works, because the label disappears but it does not appear when I hit the button.

This is the code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var estado = document.getElementById('Label1');
            estado.Visible = true;
        }
    </script>
    <div id = "bloque1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="55pt" Visible="false" />
    </div>
    <div class = "botones">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" onclick="myFunction()" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element ID is wrong, it should be `ctl00_MainContent_Label1` (or similar).
What you should really by doing is using the following method to always get the correct ID:

```
var estado = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientId %>');
```

This is because ASP's ID element isn't the same as the one on the client.

Secondly, you're looking to amend the style property of the element.

```
function myFunction() {
    var estado = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientId %>');
    estado.style.visibility = "visible"; // use hidden if you want to hide it again.
}
```

Lastly; When you set `Visible="false"` means that the Label will not render on page... you should use the style property instead `style="visibility:hidden"`.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="55pt" Visible="true" style="visibility:hidden;"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks Adriani6, I didnt expect ASP's id element is diferent on the client.

Comment: @Oriol You're welcome. If this answer helped you out mark it as correct using the tick on the left side.

Comment: Can you help one more time @Adriani6?

Comment: @Oriol That's a different question you need to ask. This, current question has already been answered.

Comment: OK Adriani6 Thanks!